# Using ForEach to create View, but how do I get onTapGesture to update immediately?

Tags: swiftui

This code works exactly like I want with a shuffle animation, except when the user taps a rectangle (in between shuffles) the color change in onTapGesture isn't updated until the next shuffle. I need to see the color change when it is tapped.
I've tried several different ways of doing this, each leads to dead end for me. Is it my data model that is way off track? Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Thanks in advance! I'm still fairly new to SwiftUI, so looking forward to learning from this.

```
import SwiftUI

class EachSpace: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    @Published var num: Int
    @Published var tapped: Bool
    @Published var highlight: Bool
    
    init(number: Int) {
        num = number
        tapped = false
        highlight = false
    }
    
}

class Column: ObservableObject, Identifiable {
    
    @Published var spaces = [EachSpace]()
    @Published var space0: EachSpace
    @Published var space1: EachSpace
    @Published var space2: EachSpace
    @Published var space3: EachSpace
    @Published var space4: EachSpace
    let id = UUID()
    
    init(low: Int, high: Int) {
        var randIntArray = [Int]()
        var tempNum = 0
        var found = false
        for _ in 0..<5 {
            repeat {
                tempNum = Int.random(in: low...high)
                if (randIntArray.firstIndex(where: {$0 == tempNum}) != nil) {
                    found = true
                } else { found = false }
            } while found
            randIntArray.append(tempNum)
        }
        space0 = EachSpace(number: randIntArray[0])
        space1 = EachSpace(number: randIntArray[1])
        space2 = EachSpace(number: randIntArray[2])
        space3 = EachSpace(number: randIntArray[3])
        space4 = EachSpace(number: randIntArray[4])

        spaces.append(space0)
        spaces.append(space1)
        spaces.append(space2)
        spaces.append(space3)
        spaces.append(space4)

    }
}

class Card: ObservableObject {

    @Published var columns = [Column]()
    @Published var columnX = Column(low: 1, high: 25)
    @Published var columnY = Column(low: 26, high: 50)
    @Published var columnZ = Column(low: 51, high: 75)
    
    init() {
        columns.append(columnX)
        columns.append(columnY)
        columns.append(columnZ)
    }
    
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var rotate = false
    @ObservedObject var card = Card()
    
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(card.columns) { col in
                    VStack {
                        ForEach(col.spaces) { space in
                            Text("\(String(space.num))")
                                .font(.system(size: 20))
                                .fontWeight(.black)
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                                .background(space.tapped ? Color.blue : Color.red)
                                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding(10)
                                .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotate ? 0 : 360))
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    space.tapped.toggle()
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0)) {
                    self.rotate.toggle()
                    self.card.columnX.spaces.shuffle()
                    self.card.columnY.spaces.shuffle()
                    self.card.columnZ.spaces.shuffle()
                }
            })
            {
                Text("Shuffle")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `@ObservedObject`/`ObservableObject` doesn't across nested observable objects - i.e. the change in `EachSpace.tapped` isn't observed by the view that's observing the root `Card` object.

The easiest fix is to move inner-most `Text` view into a separate view that will observe each `EachSpace` object directly:

```
struct SpaceView: View {
   @ObservedObject var space: EachSpace

   var body: some View {
       Text("\(String(space.num))")
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .fontWeight(.black)
            .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
            .background(space.tapped ? Color.blue : Color.red)
            .clipShape(Rectangle())
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .padding(10)
            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotate ? 0 : 360))
            .onTapGesture {
                space.tapped.toggle()
            }
   }
}
```

and change the `ForEach` in the `ContentView` to:

```
ForEach(col.spaces) { space in
   SpaceView(space: space)
}
```

Comment: That works great! Thanks so much for your help and the clear explanation!